# Joining two tables with same keys but different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, relational-database

I have two tables both all with the same fields Except for one. I want to combine these two tables with the resulting table having all the fields from both including the two fields that are not the same in each table. I.e:

lets say I have table order_debit with schema

```
order_id, date_of_order, debit_balance

5, 2019, 100
2, 2021, 30
```

and table order_credit with schema

```
order_id, date_of_order, credit_balance

1,2020, 35
2,2021, 40
```

What I want is a final table with the schema

```
order_id, date_of_order, credit_balance, debit_balance

5, 2019, 100, 0
2, 2021, 30, 40
1, 2020, 0, 35
```

I cant figure out how to do the joins without getting duplicate values, I dont think there will be too many overlaps of order_ids but there will definitely be some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, you can use `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    order_id, date_of_order, SUM(credit_balance), SUM(debit_balance)
FROM 
(
    SELECT order_id, date_of_order, 0 AS credit_balance, debit_balance FROM tbl_debit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT order_id, date_of_order, credit_balance, 0 AS debit_balance FROM tbl_credit
) FROM t
GROUP BY order_id, date_of_order
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `full join` together with `coalesce`

```
select
  coalesce(t1.order_id, t2.order_id) as order_id,
  coalesce(t1.date_of_order, t2.date_of_order) as date_of_order,
  coalesce(t1.debit_balance, 0) as debit_balance,
  coalesce(t2.credit_balance, 0) as credit_balance
from t1 
  full join t2
    on t1.order_id=t2.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want a `full join`, which MySQL does not support.  A convenient method is:

```
select od.order_id, od.date_of_order, od.debit_balance,
       coalesce(oc.credit_balance, 0) as credit_balance
from order_debit od left join
     order_credit oc
     using (order_id, date_of_order)
union all
select oc.order_id, oc.date_of_order, 0, oc.credit_balance
from order_credit oc
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_debit od
                  where od.order_id = oc.order_id and od.date_of_order = oc.date_of_order
                 );
```

Comment: You are right @GordonLinoff, `full join` feature is not supported by mysql, my mistake...